# Add images on google map in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps, geotagging

i want to show images on google map but i have no idea how to do it in android.
same like as [Panoramio](http://www.panoramio.com/map/#lt=31.529150&ln=74.353038&z=6&k=2&a=1&tab=1&pl=all)
.i have done so far,my android app capture images with latitude ,longitude save in sqllite database
.i want to populate these images on google map according to their lat,long.

Answer (score 1):

first you need to get the map, something like this

```
private GoogleMap mMap;

mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

then you can create a loop where you can add markers to the map

```
for (all the items you want to add) {

    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(LatLng(coordinates))
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.from where you have it));;
}
```

Check the info in the google developers site
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker?hl=pt-PT

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this to create a Marker with an image as icon:

```
private MarkerOptions createMarker(LatLng position, String title, String snippet, String image_path) {

    // Standard marker icon in case image is not found
    BitmapDescriptor icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory
            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED);

    if (!image_path.isEmpty()) {
        File iconfile = new File(image_path);
        if (iconfile.exists()) {
            BitmapDescriptor loaded_icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .fromPath(image_path);
            if (loaded_icon != null) {
                icon = loaded_icon;
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "loaded_icon was null");
            }
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "iconfile did not exist: "
                    + image_path);
        }
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "iconpath was empty: "
                + image_path);
    }

    return new MarkerOptions().position(position)
                    .title(title)
                    .snippet(snippet).icon(icon);
}
```